# Organization of textures, buffers and the other objects in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am creating my own game engine based on WebGL. There are objects of geometries, textures, etc. I want to create them this way:

```
new Geometry (...);
new Texture (...);
new Mesh (...);
```

and then add them to the scene or just render them in any place without addition. But how can I transfer these objects to WebGL? In fact, I create objects that are not related to WebGL. I have an option to write methods for creating these objects in my WebGL wrapper and create them like this:

```
context.createGeometry(...);
context.createTexture(...);
context.createMesh(...);
```

In these methods there will be calls like `gl.createTexture(...)`, `gl.createBuffer(...)`, etc. But this is ugly and I want to use the first way. How to "register" objects created by the first way in WebGL? I have a thought: in each object add its WebGL representation and before each render call check whether it was created, needs to update, etc. Is there a better way?

Comment: `in each object add its WebGL representation and before each render call check whether it was created, needs to update, etc` That's how I do it in my engine. You don't have much choice here since before each draw call you have to check if the right buffers/textures are attached.

Comment: @zoran404 thanks! I'll do so